# UIImage -drawAtPoint: slow on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Anyone else experience really slow performance from UIImage -drawAtPoint: ? Any tips?

Comment: sorry, which iPhone? iPhone 2G, 3G, 3GS, 4? iOS version? Size of Image? and, why are you using an UIImage with a drawAtPoint call, instead of an UIImageView?

Comment: To add to that, what type of image, how large is it, etc. Help us to help you!

Comment: How many times are you drawing it? iOS employs lazy loading — could that be anything to do with it?

Comment: Maybe slow perfomance setImage rather than -drawAtPoint? Do you use  Instruments Profiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow image drawing can happen for several reasons. In this case it was the bicubic resizing that was happening on the CPU. Solution: use images that don't need resized, pre-size or use in-built drawing routines (for things like backgrounds, gradients, etc).